# Who is tosfos anshei sheim in mishnayos

Tags: mishna, tosfot

Who is תוספות אנשי שם in משניות? When did he live? What was his occupations. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bar-Ilan's bio on him is as follows:

> R' Chaim Noach Eisenstatt was one of the Torah giants of 19th century Lithuania. He gathered insights from forty different commentaries on the Sedarim of Zeraim and Taharot from the Mishna, and compiled them into a work entitled Tosefot Anshei Shem, which he first published in Warsaw, 5647 (1887)

I can't find much more information than that about his life...

The title page on this [Mishnayos set](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=6) says much the same:

> ילקוט חדש ונפלא מבחירי מבארי המשנה ומפרשיהל נלקטו מספרים נבחרים רבים מאד

The [next page](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=7) lists the now-lost commentaries it came from.

Answer (score 1):

If you can read Hebrew, [here](https://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?cat_id=38&topic_id=2573208&forum_id=19616) is someone who gives a source that says it was ר' יהודה ליב ב"ר משה פרידלנד and he died 101 years ago.